# Monitoring Android events between closed-source applications

Tags: android, android-intent, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to reverse engineer a manufacturer-provided application that appears to be communicating with Android Services for it's operation.

Are there any utilities that can be used to eavesdrop on the IPC between two closed-source android applications? Any higher-level equivalent of ltrace/strace?

Comment: Short of a modded ROM that does this at the OS level, that's hopefully  not possible, particularly if it is all within its own process.

Comment: It's interprocess - the service process runs with privileges required to access hardware. The UI app runs with regular user privileges - and uses IPC to communicate with the service process... Besides, local root can do anything, including breakpoints in any app, so I wonder if there are any tools to do it on a higher level than strace.